# Fedora Chef Yum Issues

Tags: python, chef-infra, fedora, yum, test-kitchen

I am using Chef's Test Kitchen setup tools to test deploying onto a Fedora23 OS, and I am running into some frustrating issues with the build essentials and more specifically the python version on the system. I am trying to do basic operations like installing and configuring database, setting up servers, and in order for those to run the build essentials must be run (C code compilers, ncurses library, etc)

The package resource of Chef is supposed to use YUM as the installer for packages on Fedora, however when I run a `kitchen converge fedora` I get this at the top of the stack trace

```
Errno::ENOENT
-------------
No such file or directory - /usr/bin/python
```

which is because there is no default python installation on the system, so I tried to create a symlink with the python3 that is installed default, and that does not work either. What is interesting is the only reason that it is even trying to use the python seems to be this warning that is printed out just before execution

```
WARN: Yum executable interpreter is /bin/bash. Falling back to default python.
```

I have searched and do not know what that is trying to tell me, but assume that that is the root of my issue. Any direction that you can give me on what is going on here is really appreciated.

UPDATE:

This appears to be the source code that is causing the issue, defaulting to /usr/bin/python automatically if the shell interpreter is bash. I have no idea if I can even change this

http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/chef/Chef%2FProvider%2FPackage%2FYum%2FYumCache%3Ashabang_or_fallback